# Passing a list from Servlet to Jsp giving null pointer exception

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am trying to print a list of questions(questionList). When the form loads the elements of the list should be printed as labels.

In my java file i am returning a list of questions.

In my servlet code:

```
ArrayList<String> questionList = qd.getFormLabels();
request.setAttribute("question", questionList);
System.out.println("Hello World " + questionList);
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Home.Index.jsp");
if (rd != null){    
rd.forward(request, response);
return;
```

In my jsp code when i access this list it gives me a null pointer exception.

code of jsp:

```
<%

ArrayList<String> LabelList = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("question");
out.println(LabelList.size());

if(LabelList.isEmpty()==false)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i< LabelList.size(); i++)
        {%>
            <tr><td><%out.println(LabelList.get(i)); %></td></tr>
```

when i try to print the size it gives null. 
Please tell whether my flow is right and the servlet is triggered properly

Comment: Besides "ew?!" on a few levels, there's only a few possibilities, like list is null, wrong JSP, etc.

Comment: What's the URL in browser address bar? Is it the servlet's URL or the one of the forwarded JSP? Do you have any filters in `web.xml`? By the way, you should be using the request dispatcher from `ServletRequest`, not `ServletContext`: `request.getRequestDispatcher(...)`.

Comment: @BalusC Good point to look for explicit request modifiers.

Comment: When the application starts the URL is the /Home.Index.jsp. i am forwarding the request to this URL as the data is to be displayed on this jsp.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  But when i print the list and its size in servlet, it gives me the right size and the correct output. I think the request is not forwarded to the jsp properly. But i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Well. How exactly are you calling the servlet then? By a POST form submit? Or by a simple GET call? How exactly is this servlet mapped in `web.xml`?

Comment: Simply by get call. servlet is mapped as follows:            <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MainServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.languageline.http.MainServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

Comment: That's the servlet definition not servlet mapping. What's the `<url-pattern>` of the `<servlet-mapping>` of thie servlet? Simply opening the JSP by `/Home.Index.jsp` won't invoke the servlet. If the servlet is for example mapped on `/MainServlet`, you need to invoke it by `/MainServlet` in URL. To learn more about servlets, please read our servlets wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0):

That can only happen if you are not invoking the servlet by its URL. Based on the comments you seem to be actually invoking the JSP directly by its URL and you seem not to be understanding servlet mappings.

Well, in order to get a servlet to preprocess a HTTP request before displaying the results in a JSP, you need to map the servlet on an URL pattern in `web.xml` **and** hide the JSP away in `/WEB-INF` folder so that it can never be called directly, also not by accident, and thus you can always ensure that the JSP can only displayed by invoking the servlet.

For example, this in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.controller.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please note the `<url-pattern>` of `/home`. This takes care that the servlet can be invoked by http://localhost:8080/contextname/home where "/contextname" is actually your webapp's context name. When you enter that URL in the browser address bar or click on a link/bookmark pointing to that URL, the servlet's `doGet()` method will be called. You only need to change those `RequestDispatcher` lines

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Home.Index.jsp");
if (rd != null){    
rd.forward(request, response);
```

to the following simpler and more canonical form

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

You also need to move the JSP file to `/WEB-INF` folder on exactly that path. I've for the sake of clarity renamed the JSP file name. `Home.Index.jsp` is a rather strange name. You can always rename it back if you want, as long as it's inside the `/WEB-INF` folder.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Explains how servlets work and contains concrete Hello World examples